# Switch partition into existing table

Tags: sap-ase

Oracle and SQL Server have this feature which allows to switch a tables partition into an existing table (its discussed for example [here](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/19/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/)). I am unable to find a similar feature for Sybase ASE.

**Question Part A**: Is there a way to switch partitions in Sybase ASE?

If the answer is 'no' I am unsure how to proceed. My situtation is that I have a very large table which is indexed by dates. Now I need to add data for a new Date T_n+1.

```
large table             new
--------------------   ------
|T1|T2|T3| .... |Tn| + |Tn+1|
--------------------   ------
```

The insert is fast enough if I drop the index on the table first, but the recreation of the index takes a lot of time. There has to be a better way!

**Question Part B**: what is the fastest way to add this data for Tn+1 into the large table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer Part A:**

While Sybase ASE supports **move partition** and **merge partition**, these commands work within a single table, ie, Sybase ASE does not support the movement of partitions between (different) tables.

**Answer Part B:**

Assuming dropping and recreating indices is too expensive (in terms of time; in terms of users needing indices to access other partitions), you're not left with a lot of options to speed up the inserts other than some basics:

- bulk insert
- minimize the number of transactions (ie, reduce number of times you have to write to the log)
- disable triggers for the session inserting the data [obviously you would need to decide how to handle any must-have logic that resides in the trigger]
- bump up the lock escalation threshold (for the table) to insure you don't escalate to a table-level exclusive lock; only of interest if you can't afford to block other users with a table-level exclusive lock; may need to bump up the **number of locks** configuration setting; less of an issue with ASE 16.0+ since the insert should only escalate to a partition-level lock
- if you are replicating out of this table you may want to consider the overhead of replicating the insert vs directly inserting the data into the replicate table(s) [would obviously require disabling replication of the inserts to the primary table]